# Faster than cmd+Tab way for app switching?

Tags: keyboard, macos

Is there a faster way to switch between currently-open applications on the Mac than using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

I tend to have a lot of different apps open at a time and I have to keep switching between three-to-four of these apps all the time. And having to repeatedly hit cmd+tab,tab,tab seems like a waste of keystrokes. It would be nice if there was a faster way to achieve this application-switching.

This does not have to be built-in Mac functionality. I'd like to know about any app that does this job better.

PS: I'm running Mavericks
PPS: I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut and not a mouse-related solution.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to for example turn the right option into an extra modifier key for opening applications:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_FINDER</name>
    <url>file:///System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <vkopenurldef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SAFARI</name>
    <url>file:///Applications/Safari.app</url>
  </vkopenurldef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::VK_MODIFIER_EXTRA1</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_FINDER</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SAFARI</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html for more examples.

If you have bought the Powerpack for [Alfred 2](http://www.alfredapp.com), you can use workflows like this:

[image]

Hotkeys have a short delay by default, but you can reduce it by changing the trigger behavior:

[image]

Comment: I love this idea and I think this is the fastest for me given that I know I have just 4-5 applications that I regularly switch between. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is a really old question but just thought I would add to it anyway!

I use [apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/).

Really simple toolbar app that can open/switch to almost anything with custom keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: and it is free!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a personnal suggestion : Use the power of Mission control.

I link to a mouse button (lateral wheel click) show All Windows / show application windows . With that shortcut it's realy fast to just from one Window/App to another.

---

Edit: Didn't saw your PPS. But Mission control is still a nice way to handle multiple apps/windows !

Other possibility, you could link a keyboard shortcut to an automator service which would switch to a particular app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matthieu. Do you have any examples for the automator-service you suggest?

Comment: I switch using command-1, command-2, etc; and have particular apps on particular desktops (and told Mavericks not to rearrange the desktops).

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [QuickSilver](http://qsapp.com/), which lets you switch to or open apps and various other things through keyboard only.

Comment: Ah yes. I use Alfred but hadn't thought about using the launcher to instead switch to an already launched application. (Silly me!). On an average it's actually more key-strokes than cmd+tabbing but at least do not have to look at the screen to check if I've to tab left and right or count the number of tabs I've to make. I guess this is the quickest way yet. Thanks Edouard! :)